# React state is changing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a list (news), it comes from the server and each object has multiple fields that the user can edit. I'm saving the list in a state called `originalData`, and I'm saving the first news item in a state called `activeNews`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/api/published/news_published_english').then(res => res.json()).then(news =>{
        if(news && news.rows[0]){
            const new_news = [...news.rows];
            this.setState({originalData:[...news.rows]});
            this.setState({activeNews:new_news[0].doc.content});
        }
    });
}
```

When the user clicks on another news item, `activeNews` will change to the selected index. `handleChange` takes the index the of the field that the user want to change within the active news item and its value:

```
handleChange(index, value) {  
    const x = [...this.state.news];
    x[index].value = value;
    this.setState({ news: x });

    console.log("original", this.state.originalData);
    console.log("news", news);
}
```

Now the problem is why `originalData` keeps updating with the values that the user changes? I want `originalData` to not change but it keeps changing in the handleChange function!

This is the only place where I called `setState` on `originalData` but it keeps changing to the value that is getting passed to `handleChange`.

```
this.setState({ originalData: [...news.rows] });
```

Comment: As the answers provided below.. you should NEVER mutate current state variables.. make a copy of them, update values then set that new value as state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mutating the original objects in your `handleChange` function when you do this:

```
x[index].value = value;
```

To better show what's happening, I'm going to expand your code a bit

```
handleChange(index, value) {  
    const copiedArray = [...this.state.news];
    const originalObject = copiedArray[index];
    originalObject.value = value;
    this.setState({ news: copiedArray });
}
```

As I've eluded to with the variable names here, even though you've created a new array - the object at `this.state.news[index]` and `copiedArray[index]` are the same object - so changing `.value` will change in both places. In order to solve this, you need to do a deep clone. You can do this by finding a library (like lodash) which can do this, or you can take a quicker solution and change your code as follows:

```
handleChange(index, value) {  
    const copiedArray = [...this.state.news];
    const originalObject = copiedArray[index];
    const copiedObject = Object.assign({}, originalObject);
    copiedObject.value = value;
    copiedArray[index] = copiedObject;
    this.setState({ news: copiedArray });
}
```

Or a condensed version of the same thing:

```
handleChange(index, value) {  
    const arr = [...this.state.news];
    arr[index] = { ...arr[index], value };
    this.setState({ news: arr });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake in react apps, you are creating a copy of the array `this.state.news` which is an array of objects.

When you do `x[index].value = value` you are actually modifying the original object that is still being referenced in `this.state.news`.

This --> `const x = [...this.state.news];` makes a copy of the array but not the objects, they are still referencing the original objects.

What you need to be doing is something like this:

```
const news = this.state.news.map((x, i) => {
  if (i === index) {
    return {...x, value};
  } else return x
})
this.setState({ news })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `x[index].value = value` is modifying the original array, which is why it is broken. You could write your change handler like this:

```
handleChange(index, value) {
    this.setState(state => (
        { news: state.news.map((item, i) => i === index
            ? { ...item, value } 
            : item
        }
    ));
}
```

Note that I am using a callback function in setState, this is recommended when your new state is dependend on previous state.

**EDIT** Actually, there is no need to map over the whole array, because you already know the index. Look at caesay's answer which is better performancewise:

```
 handleChange(index, value) {
    this.setState(state => {
        const newsCopy = [ ...state.news ];
        newsCopy [index] = { ...arr[index], value };
        return { news: newsCopy };
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have been seeing code like this around a lot --> `this.state.news.map((item, i) => i === index ? value : item })` could you explain to me how this actually works? Is this some shorthand for modifying the `value` property in the current item?

Comment: @deowk: it does the same thing as you do in your answer except it uses a Conditional (ternary) operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Description

Comment: @caesay but would this not result in an array that contains the unmodified objects and then just the `value` i.e `[{...}, {...}, 'someValue']`?

Comment: @deowk Yes, in this case, this is a bug - it should look like this: `this.state.news.map((item, i) => i === index ? { ...item, value } : item });`